# Need explanation of problem in Temam (convergence, weak derivatives)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $V \subset H \subset V$ be Hilbert triple. We have $u_m$ is infinite differentiable from $[0,T]$ to $V$.

Suppose $u_m \to u$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$ and $u_m' \to u'$ in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$

Suppose that it is true that
$$\frac{d}{dt}|u_m(t)|_H^2  = 2\langle u'_m(t), u_m(t) \rangle_{V^*, V}\tag{1}$$ for each $m$.

From the convergences above, it follows that
$$|u_m|^2_H \to |u|^2_H$$  and 
$$\langle u'_m(t), u_m(t) \rangle_{V^*, V} \to \langle u'(t), u(t) \rangle_{V^*, V}$$
both in in $L^1(0,T)$.

> These convergences also hold in the distribution sense; therefore we are
>   allowed to pass to the limit in (1) in the distribution sense; in the
>   limit we find precisely
>   $$\frac{d}{dt}|u(t)|_H^2  = 2\langle u'(t), u(t) \rangle_{V^*, V}$$

How does this work exactly? What does he mean by "also hold in distribution sense?" How to pass to the limit in the $\frac{d}{dt}$ term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a function $\varphi \in C^\infty([0,T])$. By (1) you know
$$\int_0^T \frac{d}{dt}|u_m|_H^2 \, \varphi \, dt = 2 \, \int_0^T \langle u_m', u_m \rangle_{V^*,V} \, \varphi \, dt.$$
Integrating by parts yields
$$-\int_0^T |u_m|_H^2 \, \frac{d}{dt} \varphi dt = 2 \, \int_0^T \langle u_m', u_m \rangle_{V^*,V} \, \varphi \, dt.$$
Now, you can pass to the limit $m \to \infty$ and obtain
$$-\int_0^T |u|_H^2 \, \frac{d}{dt} \varphi dt = 2 \, \int_0^T \langle u', u \rangle_{V^*,V} \, \varphi \, dt.$$
This yields
$$\int_0^T \frac{d}{dt}|u|_H^2 \, \varphi \, dt = 2 \, \int_0^T \langle u', u \rangle_{V^*,V} \, \varphi \, dt.$$
Since $\varphi \in C^\infty([0,1])$ was arbitrary, this shows
$$\frac d{dt} |u|_H^2 = \langle u', u\rangle_{V^*,V}$$
almost everywhere in $(0,T)$.

The phrase "hold in the distributional" sense means, that we have convergence if we see $|u_m|_H^2$ (and its temporal derivative) and $\langle u_m', u_m\rangle_{V^*,V}$ as distributions. This is (more or less) equivalently to what I have done above.

Comment: thank you! Can you just explain how you went from the LHS of your third equation to the LHS of your fourth? I guess it's IBP but are you allowed to assume that $\frac{d}{dt}|u|^2_H$ exists?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit sloppy. But the third line already yields that the weak derivative of $|u|_H^2$ is $2\,\langle u', u\rangle_{V^*,V}$.

Comment: I agree now. So we only have it in a weak sense. In a Galerkin method, one uses this to get a energy estimate, but I thought we always needed the strong differentiability for that. Does it still work out if we only have weak? Because we need to integrate in time and I am not sure if we can do that and "cancel out the d by dt" if it's only weak.

Comment: If you have a function $v \in L^1(0,T)$, then its antiderivative $V(t) = \int_0^t v \, dt$ belongs to $L^\infty(0,T)$ and the $L^\infty$-norm is bounded by the $L^1$-norm of $v$. Using this for $v = \frac d{dt}|u|_H^2$ you get the desired energy estimate, or I miss something?